# Python interpreter doesn't display stdout with a file as input

Tags: python, database, db2, stdout

I have simple test code to make a DB2 connection and display output from the tables function:

```
import ibm_db
import sys
cn=ibm_db.connect('SAMPLE','db2admin','******')
import ibm_db_dbi
conn=ibm_db_dbi.Connection(cn)
conn.tables('SYSCAT','%')
sys.stdout.flush()
conn.close()
```

This code works fine when each line is executed interactively with correct output, but when put into a file and executed as: python db2.py, the script executes but the conn.tables output doesn't display to stdout. I added the sys.stdout.flush() call but it still doesn't display. I've searched but no luck. 
I'm using Anaconda python on Windows 10. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might try printing something...

Comment: The interactive interpreter will try and output any values returned to the interpreter (e.g. `conn.tables('SYSCAT', '%')`) whereas a python program doesn't - see @thebjorn's comment

Comment: I added 'print "hello" and it does print ok. I'm new to Python obviously. Embarrassed but I'll get over it.

Comment: Maybe got a `blank` db or returned unprintable object(so buffer memory)